# From series to matplotlib-acceptable format

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have grouped some variables using groupby and now I want to plot them and edit the plot using matplotlib. In the code below, I have ploted the data using pandas, which gives me very little room to edit the graph (I think).

```
a = df_08.groupby('new_time').symbol.count()/len(set(df_08['date']))  
a.plot()
```

The problem with using matplotlib and doing

```
plt.plot()
```

is that my data for 'a', after using 'groupby' is not in Series format for pandas and matplotlib does not accept that.

'a' comes out like this, in Series format:

new_time    symbol

09:30   224.2

09:31   133.8

09:32   117.6

09:33   113.5

09:34   108.4

The first column has the name 'Index', but I can't seem to treat it as the column name. I would like the first column to be on the x axis and the second column to be on the y axis.

Anyway, I guess my question is how to transform the data from Series to matplotlib acceptable format.

Comment: You can't access the index as `df_08['index']`, but `df_08.index` should work? But as always, a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be very helpful...

Comment: That works to find the time column, but this column is not really an index after doing groupby. I dk...